# Expiry time for member in Redis

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I'm using Jedis client to store geo coordinates in Redis.

Is there any way to set expiry time for member in Redis? I know, I can set the expiry time for a key.

For example, I added below three coordinates and now I want to expire "Bahn" member in 10 secs.

```
redis.geoadd(key, 8.6638775, 49.5282537, "Weinheim"); 
redis.geoadd(key, 8.3796281, 48.9978127, "EFS9");
redis.geoadd(key, 8.665351, 49.553302, "Bahn");
```

Comment: There's no built-in support for that. What's your scenario?

Comment: I'm storing geo location of few users and I want to expire those locations after some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the scene, GEOADD uses a ZSET to store its data.

You can store the same data (without geolocation) in a second ZSET, with a unix timestamp as score this time, using a regular ZADD command.

```
ZADD expirationzset <expiration date> <data>
```

You can get the expired data from this second ZSET, using

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE expirationzset -inf <current unix timestamp>
```

Then you have to remove them from both ZSETs, using ZREM for the geolocation ZSET, and ZREMRANGEBYSCORE for the expiration zset:

```
ZREM geolocationzset <expired_data1> <expired_data3> <expired_data3>...
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE expirationzset -inf <current unix timestamp>
```

Comment: thanks! I was able to implement a logic in Java based on this.